# Not comparing the correct vector elements

Tags: c++, input, vector

I'm taking in a text file and putting the words into a vector. If the vector already contains the word, it will increment the occurance memeber. If it's a new word, we push it onto the vector. When I debug this, everything seems correct, but the vector is filled with every single word, with occurance = 1 because "i" seems to be one index behind.

If I initialize with i=1 though, the the vector will go out of range. Any help?

```
vector<wordFreq> words;

//already have 1 in vector, i initialized at 0.

while(!myfile.eof())
{

        myfile >> tempWord;                     //takes word into variable

        if (words[i].wordName == tempWord)      //if it is found
        {

            //words[i].occurances++;      //increment occurance member

        }
        else
        {
            //create new object
            wordFreq tempElement;
            tempElement.occurances = 1;
            tempElement.wordName = tempWord;
            words.push_back (tempElement);      //push onto vector

        }

        i++;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your language.

Comment: To start off, this: `while(!myfile.eof())` [**is wrong.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). And if you have the latitude to use a [`std::map<std::string,unsigned int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) rather than just a vector, this becomes trivial quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `while(!myfile.eof()) myfile >> tempWord` to

```
while ( myfile >> tempWord )
```

Otherwise you will get an extra loop iteration with a junk word.

Anyway, it sounds like you want to loop through the whole vector for each word to find this, e.g.:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    if ( words[i] == tempWord )
    {
        ++words[i].occurances;
        break;
    }

if ( i == words.size() )   // not found
{
// create new object...
}
```

While this will work fine, there are standard algorithms that will do the job for you, specifically the `find` function. Check the documentation for `find` and see if you can replace your `for` loop with a `find`.

Finally, if you use a `std::map` instead of a vector than you can replace this entire block of code with `++my_map[tempWord].occurances;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a map can help you if you just want to count the words' occurance:

```
map<string, int> m;
string tempWord;
while (myfile >> tempWord) ++m[tempWord];

// print out
for (map<string, int>::const_iterator p = m.begin(); p != m.end(); ++p) {
    cout << p->first << '\t' << p->second << '\n';
}
```